# Can I use RSync/Rclone to sync GCS buckets in production workloads?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, rsync, production, rclone

I have a requirement to have Business Continuity Disaster Recovery solution on GCP. A storage bucket is involved in Primary Data Centre. I have done some research and came to conclusion that Rsync/Rclone cab be used to sync the data from PDC to SDC?

Is Rsync suggestible in production workloads?

Can anyone contrast the Rsync with Rclone? Is Rclone standard for production?

Comment: 1) Ask one well-defined question. 2) This is a programming site. 3) Do not ask for opinions or recommendations. 4) You must do your own research. Stack Overflow is not a code writing or tutorial service. We help you solve software development-type questions. 5) Neither rsync/rclone support Google Cloud Storage. The CLI **gsutil** provides some rsync features. Please read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.